# java homework(recursion)

Tags: java, recursion

This is the question:

> #### Problem  I.
>
> We define the Pestaina strings as follows:
>
> 1. ab is a Pestaina string.
> 2. cbac is a Pestaina string.
> 3. If S is a Pestaina string, so is SaS.
> 4. If U and V are Pestaina strings, so is UbV.
>
> Here a, b, c are constants and S,U,V are variables. In these rules,
>   the same letter represents the same string. So, if S = ab, rule 3
>   tells us that abaab is a Pestaina string. In rule 4, U and V represent
>   Grandpa strings, but they may be different.
>
> Write the method
>
> ```
> public static boolean isPestaina(String in)
> ```
>
> That returns true if in is a Pestaina string and false otherwise.

And this is what i have so far which only works for the first rule, but the are some cases in which doesnt work for example "abaaab":

```
public class Main {

private static boolean bool = true;
    public static void main(String[] args){

        String pestaina = "abaaab";
        System.out.println(pestaina+" "+pestainaString(pestaina));
    }

    public static boolean pestainaString(String p){

        if(p == null || p.length() == 0 || p.length() == 3) {
            return false;
        }
        if(p.equals("ab")) {
            return true;
        }
        if(p.startsWith("ab")){

            bool = pestainaString(p, 1);
        }else{
            bool = false;
        }
        return bool;
    }

    public static boolean pestainaString(String p, int sign){

        String letter;
        char concat;

        if("".equals(p)){

            return false;
        }


        if(p.length() < 3){

            letter = p;
            concat = ' ';
            p = "";
            pestainaString(p);

        }else if(p.length() == 3 && (!"ab".equals(p.substring(0, 2)) || p.charAt(2) != 'a')){
            letter = p.substring(0, 2);
            concat = p.charAt(2);
            p = "";
            pestainaString(p);
        }else{
            letter = p.substring(0, 2);
            concat = p.charAt(2);
            pestainaString(p.substring(3));
        }

        if(letter.length() == 2 && concat == ' '){
            if(!"ab".equals(letter.trim())){

                bool = false;
                //concat = 'a';
            }

        }else if((!"ab".equals(letter)) || (concat != 'a')){

            bool = false;
        }
        System.out.println(letter +" " + concat);
       return bool;
    }
}
```

Please tell me what i have done wrong.

Comment: Please don't use the homework tag. It has been deprecated.

Comment: FYI, the community recently decided to [deprecate the homework tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated). Please don't use it on new questions. Thanks!

Comment: It should be moved to the homework section. Or more like the overview section like one of my earlier questions that also used the homework tag.

Comment: homework tag is no longer there

Comment: This is a brute force approach, hopefully the next lesson will be parsing...

Comment: What do u mean @Tony Hopkinson

Comment: @LexyFeito once you get to learn parsing theory, you'd never take the approach you have. eg if S was Fred and a was Wilma, FredWilmaFred might be be parsed to <V0><C0><V0> then your test to see if it was a Pestaina would be trivial...

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a [Context Free Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language), which can be described as a [Context Free Grammer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) and parsed with it. The field of parsing these is widely researched and there is a lot of resources for it out there.

The wikipedia page also discusses some [algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Parsing_algorithms) to parse these, specifically - I think you are interested in the [Early Parsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earley_algorithm)

I also believe this "language" can be parsed using a [push down automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton) (though not 100% sure about it).

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem i was calling the wrong method.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String text = "cbacacbac";


        System.out.println("Is \""+ text +"\" a Pestaina string? " + isPestaina(text));



    }

    public static boolean isPestaina(String in) {
        if (in.equals("ab")) {
            return true;
        }
        if (in.equals("cbac")) {
            return true;
        }
        if (in.length() > 3) {
            if ((in.startsWith("ab") || in.startsWith("cbac"))
                    && (in.endsWith("ab") || in.endsWith("cbac"))) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That was fun.

```
public boolean isPestaina(String p) {
        Set<String> existingPestainas = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"ab", "cbac"}));
        boolean isP  = false;
        int lengthParsed = 0;
        do {
            if (lengthParsed > 0) {
                //just realized there's a touch more to do here for the a/b
                //connecting rules...I'll leave it as an excersize for the readers.
                if (p.substring(lengthParsed).startsWith("a") ||
                    p.substring(lengthParsed).startsWith("b")) {
                    //good connector.
                    lengthParsed++;
                } else {
                    //bad connector;
                    return false;
                }
            }
            for (String existingP : existingPestainas) {
                if (p.substring(lengthParsed).startsWith(existingP)) {
                    isP = true;
                    lengthParsed += existingP.length();
                }
            }
            if (isP) {
                System.err.println("Adding pestaina: " + p.substring(0, lengthParsed));
                existingPestainas.add(p.substring(0, lengthParsed));
            }
        } while (isP && p.length() >= lengthParsed + 1);
        return isP;
    }
```

Comment: i was supposed to do it using recursion

Comment: a much more challenging pestaina is abaabbcbacbabaabaabbcbacbab.  I think it's safe to say if you're program correctly results to true for that pestaina, you've done a good job. ;)